# what is the best email type to request for Phd position

Tags: email

Recently I have found a great PHD position which on some aspect exactly fit with my CV. 
I am looking for the best email type to introduce my self to the professor? what information are necessary on my email.

Do you show me any examples or links?

Comment: The most important thing in the e-mail is to explain to the professor **why** the PhD position which on some aspect exactly fit with your CV.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer the 5 W's: Who, What, Where, When, and Why.

Honestly my thought is skip the full introduction in the email. Instead, state that you are a phd student, and you believe the position fit in with your cv and you wish to have a in person meeting/or phone meeting to discuss this. Keep the email short and sweet. Once you meet the professor, discuss with him.

Comment: or her... I would prefer to have a very short version of who the applicant is and the salient points of their CV in the email, so that I can assess whether to offer a phone meeting or schedule a face-2-face meeting.

Comment: This is really bad advice because the email must be customized owing to the large number of people bulk mailing non-customized requests for PhD positions.